# Display the newest file in directory of music files, php

Tags: php

I have a directory with many subdirectories. These sub directories act as "playlists" (they contain many music files). The code below will show all of the subdirectories (or playlists). I want to display Only ONE, and I want it to be the newest subdirectory created. So I I run the code now it should display only one and only the newest directory.

```
$y=0;

        foreach(glob('../music/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $playlist) {
            $y=$y+1;

            echo "\n";
            echo '<div class="mp_content" id="c_album_'.$y.'">';
            echo "\n";
            echo '<img src="music/album1/album.jpg" alt="album1"/>';
            echo "\n";
          }
```

Comment: How would u determine that directory is the newest?

Comment: http://php.net/stat   loop on your results, find the directories, then keep track of which one's "newest".

Comment: You can try this: `$latest_ctime = 0;` and then in the foreach you can do a check like: `if (filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) { $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath); }` Also note, that there is no "last change" in Windows only a create date

Comment: but how to show ONLY first one, the code lists them all

Comment: If you want to show only one result then don't run foreach loop. Get the result of glob function with $playlists = glob('../music/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); and after that get the first result from an array of results using $firstList = $playlists[0];

Answer (score 0):

1 Get directory lists by glob.
2 Sort lists by filectime.
3 Get a result if it exists.

```
$lists = glob('../work/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
usort($lists, function($a, $b){return filectime($a) <= filectime($b);});
if(isset($lists[0])) {
    print($lists[0]);
}
```

It will give you only one and only the newest directory.